# Facebook SDK integration with Fragments in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, tabs, android-fragments

I'm using the default tab+swipe template for an Android app, and am trying to include Facebook integration. My app looks like this: MainActivity has two tabs - the tab contents of one of them includes a Login button for Facebook.

However, the tutorial on the [Facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) (Step 6) only includes code for use with an Activity. I'm having trouble implementing this for a Fragment. I want to login to FB an retrieve FB user data only when I click on the Login button in the fragment corresponding to the first tab.

Here's the fragment code:

```
    /**
 * A fragment representing a section of the app.
 */
public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment
{
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public SectionFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == tabSection.FACEBOOK.ordinal())
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);

            Button loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //login to Facebook on click
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
        else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == tabSection.CONTACTS.ordinal())
        { 
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

            return view;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the Facebook tutorial code:

```
package com.firstandroidapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// start Facebook Login
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

  // callback when session changes state
  @Override
  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {

      // make request to the /me API
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
          if (user != null) {
            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

}
```

All these callback methods correspond to an activity, not a fragment. I need help putting them in a fragment and calling only on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Facebook example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) might be more along the lines of what you're lookig for. You can either use the already defined `UserSettingsFragment` or use the LoginButton class and a Fragment that you define yourself.

Comment: OK. But I still have to check for the savedInstanceState in the main activity and display a fragment. This shows the Facebook fragment regardless of the FragmentPagerAdapter. I want it to be such that every time I swipe to the Facebook tab, it should act as though the Facebook activity is being started.